# How to retain the order of items (from server) for a key-index object after normalizing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I am working on a react asp.net application. From the server, I return a list of items, ordered by date. Then, I normalize it using `normalizr`:

```
axios.get(url, { params: { userId, submissionId } })
     .then(response => {
            const notifications = new schema.Entity('notifications');
            const normalizedData = normalize(response.data, [notifications]);
            dispatch(
                fetchNotificationsSuccess(normalizedData.entities.notifications)
           );
        })
        .catch(error => { notificationDataOperationFailure(error) });
```

When I run this, the items are reordered by their key values starting from 1. I wonder how I can retain the order sent from the server.

Comment: An object in JS is technically an unordered set of key-value pairs. Or in other words, you should not rely their order. If you want order, you should use an Array or a Map. In your specific case, I'd get the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and sort them. After normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the order in the "result" you get, see more info here: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/9